# Greasemonkey script to move an element into another element?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, userscripts

I want to move `<div>` elements. In this case, swap the first and last `div.clearfix`.  So this:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="clearfix ">
        <label for="form-title">Title</label>
        <div class="input"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix "></div>
    <div class="clearfix ">
        <label>Verification</label>
        <div dir="ltr">
            recaptcha
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Would become this:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="clearfix ">
        <label>Verification</label>
        <div dir="ltr">
             recaptcha
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix "></div>
    <div class="clearfix ">
        <label for="form-title">Title</label>
        <div class="input"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I've searched but all I've got is moving (¿screen?) position, not as I want. 
How do I swap those `<div>`s?

Comment: So you want to swap the first and last `div.clearfix`, or something else?

Comment: yes, i want to swap last clearfix and first clearfix, can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To swap the first and last `div.clearfix`s, given that HTML, use the 
`querySelector`, `insertBefore`, and `appendChild` functions.

Here is **a complete Greasemonkey script** that does that:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Swap first and last div.clearfix
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var container    = document.querySelector ("fieldset");
var firstTargDiv = container.querySelector ("fieldset > div.clearfix:first-child");
var lastTargDiv  = container.querySelector ("fieldset > div.clearfix:last-child");

//-- Swap last to first.
container.insertBefore (lastTargDiv, firstTargDiv);

//-- Move old first to last.
container.appendChild (firstTargDiv);
```

Comment: That's because that fiddle **DOES NOT MATCH THE CODE FROM THE QUESTION!**  See http://jsfiddle.net/EbXcs/ for a match to the new, **changed** HTML.  Please also include exact, accurate details in questions.  For userscripts questions, the unaltered target-page HTML is best.