# Greasemonkey: Unable to move div classes

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, userscripts, twitch

I've been trying to use a personal grease/tampermonkey script for use on twitch.tv

Currently I'm trying to move stats and stream-config-status to be above the dash-hostmode-contain. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079725/greasemonkey-script-to-move-an-element-into-another-element) post and tried re-working it to fit what I want. This is what I had setup http://jsfiddle.net/7L2s180s/3/  But I am pretty inexperienced so I failed.

```html
<div class="grid c7" id="controls_column">
    <div class="dash-broadcast-control">title broadcast</div>
    <div class="dash-hostmode-contain"> you are not being hosted</div>
    <div class="dash-hosting-contain" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="dash-player-contain js-dash-player-contain">----</div>
    <div id="stats"> x people are watching</div>
    <div id="stream-config-status">good quality</div>
</div>
```

My end goal would be this, I just haven't figured out to get those two to move yet.

```html
<div class="grid c7" id="controls_column">
    <div class="dash-broadcast-control">title broadcast</div>
    <div id="stats"> x people are watching</div>
    <div id="stream-config-status">good quality</div>
    <div class="dash-hostmode-contain"> you are not being hosted</div>
    <div class="dash-hosting-contain" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="dash-player-contain js-dash-player-contain">----</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your issue?

Comment: I was unable to move the "stats" and "stream-config-status" above the "dash-hostmode-contain" class

Comment: Have a look at my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1. When using `querySelector()`, you need to add the `#` prefix to *all* strings that represent ids and the `.` prefix to *all* strings that represent class names.
2. You had a typo in `#stream-config-status`.

Have a look at this updated version of your JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7L2s180s/5/

As a general tip, in the future you can use the developer console of all major browsers to debug an error like this. Simply press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open it. It will show you most error messages.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks TimoSta. Feeling pretty stupid that I missed that.